# SQL Athena lookup function

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have my table like this one:

| current_date | conversion1 | conversion2 | conversion3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 0.5 | 0.7 | 0.9 |
| 2021-10-02 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 0.8 |
| 2021-10-03 | 0.3 | 0.5 | 0.0 |
| 2021-10-04 | 0.2 | 0.0 | 0.0 |

And I want to move my data one down according dates (like excel's lookup function).

1 day down for column conversion1

2 days down for column conversion2

3 days down for column conversion3

Desired output should look like this:

| current_date | conversion1 | conversion2 | conversion3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 2021-10-02 | 0.5 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 2021-10-03 | 0.4 | 0.7 | 0.0 |
| 2021-10-04 | 0.3 | 0.6 | 0.9 |

Thanx for helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `LAG`?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LAG.html

Something like this should work

### Select Statement

```
SELECT date,
       coalesce(lag(conversion1) over (order by date), 0) conversion1,
       coalesce(lag(conversion2, 2) over (order by date), 0) conversion2,
       coalesce(lag(conversion3, 3) over (order by date), 0) conversion3
FROM TBL
```

### Schema Build

```
  tbl (
    Date date,
    conversion1 float,
    conversion2 float,
    conversion3 float
  );

INSERT INTO
  tbl
VALUES
  ('2020-10-01', 0.5, 0.7, 0.9),
  ('2020-10-02', 0.4, 0.6, 0.8),
  ('2020-10-03', 0.3, 0.5, 0),
  ('2020-10-04', 0.2, 0, 0)
```

SQL Fiddle (Postgres):
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8bd32/4

Comment: While this will work note that Athena is not Redshift but Presto and in some cases functions/ syntax differ. Also `lag` has an option to [specify default value](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#lag) so you can simplify query a bit by removing `coalesce`.